# How do I access the rank

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm tryiing to run this query in Postgresql. I get the results I want, but I'm trying to limit the results to a value in a column. However, it doesn't let me access the column:

```
select count(event), event, u.userid, u.campaign_id, 
rank() over (partition by u.campaign_id order by count(event) desc) as THISHERE 
from events e join users u on u.userid = e.userid 
where THISHERE=1 
group by event, 3 , 4 
order by 1 desc 
limit 20;
```

ERROR:  column "thishere" does not exist

Comment: You cannot reference a column alias (`thishere`) in the where clause of the same query. That's why it didn't work. So use a subquery instead which does then allow access to that column alias. *also* if you are literally only ever expecting 1 row for each group, use ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK() as the latter can repeat numbers (more than 1 thing can have the same rank)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a subquery:

```
select eu.*
from (select count(event), event, u.userid, u.campaign_id, 
             rank() over (partition by u.campaign_id order by count(event) desc) as THISHERE 
      from events e join
           users u
           on u.userid = e.userid 
      group by event, 3 , 4 
     ) eu
where THISHERE = 1 
order by 1 desc 
limit 20;
```

I think you can also do what you want using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (campaign_id) count(event), event, u.userid, u.campaign_id, 
             rank() over (partition by u.campaign_id order by count(event) desc) as THISHERE 
from events e join
     users u
     on u.userid = e.userid 
group by event, 3 , 4
order by campaign_id, count(event) desc
fetch first 20 rows only;
```

Comment: thanks! i've been trying the distinct on, but the syntax doesn't make sense to me - the postgres docs don't really do a good job. would you mind explaining how it works with dummy vars?